# Is there any way to make the method that create points in specific size to be faster?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The method is in a new class and i use it from form1:
In the top of the new class:

```
public int numberOfPoints = 100;
```

The class Init method:

```
public void Init()
        {
if (IsEmpty(bmpWithPoints) == true)
            {
                bmpWithPoints = GetBitmapWithEllipses(1.0f);
            }
        }
```

Then the method:

```
private Bitmap GetBitmapWithEllipses(float radius)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
            {
                g.Clear(Color.Black);
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                //store the Ellipses in a GraphicsPath
                using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gP = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPoints; x++)
                    {
                        for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPoints; y++)
                        {
                            Color c = Color.FromArgb(
                                r.Next(0, 256),
                                r.Next(0, 256),
                                r.Next(0, 256));

                            using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(c))
                            {
                                Point pt = new Point(r.Next(bmp.Width), r.Next(bmp.Height));

                                //clone and widen the path to determine, whether the new point overlaps
                                using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gP2 = (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath)gP.Clone())
                                {
                                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.White, radius))
                                    {
                                        gP2.Widen(pen);
                                        while (gP2.IsVisible(pt.X, pt.Y) || gP2.IsOutlineVisible(pt, pen))
                                        {
                                            pt = new Point(r.Next(bmp.Width), r.Next(bmp.Height));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                RectangleF rc = new RectangleF(pt.X - radius, pt.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
                                g.FillEllipse(sb, rc);
                                gP.StartFigure();
                                gP.AddEllipse(rc);
                                gP.CloseFigure();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return bmp;
        }
```

And in Form1:

```
public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox1.Text = trackBar1.Maximum.ToString();
            de.pb1 = pictureBox1;

            de.bmpWithPoints = new Bitmap(512, 512);
            de.numberOfPoints = 20;
            de.randomPointsColors = true;
            de.Init();
        }
```

When i set the number of points in form1 to 10 for example it will work fast the method and return the bmp with 10 points fast.
But if i set in form1 the number of points to 20 it will take about 3-5 seconds.
If i set it to 50 points in form1 it will take some minutes.

1. What should be the limit maximum points to be able to set ? The size of the image is 512, 512. So it's logical i will be able to fill all the image with points that's 512*512 = 262144 logical i mean by the user. The user can set the number of points and the size of them. In this example it's 1.0f the radius of each point.
2. How can i make it the method GetBitmapWithEllipses to create the points faster ?

Comment: "How do I improve my code?" These kinds of questions are better suited for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is more for problems in getting the code to work.

Comment: So you want to generate `numberOfPoints` non-overlapping circles of radius `radius`?

Comment: @Abion47 Not necessarily.  If there is a specific question about improving the algorithm used to solve the problem, it may be on-topic for SO.  The question is about improving the algorithm, not just improving code quality.

Comment: The *numberOfPoints* variable name is excessively misleading, it does not set the number of points at all.  This code has O(n^3) complexity, always scales very poorly.  The cycle stealers here are GraphicsPath.IsVisible() and the very nasty while() loop, a loop that has a serious risk of *never* completing.   You'll have to throw this code away, it is not fit to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

this is how it works ^^ oh and you are creating more than you want I think.
if you enter 10 it will create 100. if you enter 4 you get 16. numberof points * numberofpoints

anyway here is what you want i think (remove one loop if you want the exact number of points you entered)^^

```
    private Bitmap GetBitmapWithEllipses(float radius)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);
        Random r = new Random();

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            List<RectangleF> rects = new List<RectangleF>();
            rects.Add(new RectangleF(0, 0, 0, 0));

            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPoints; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPoints; y++)
                {
                    Color c = Color.FromArgb(
                        r.Next(0, 256),
                        r.Next(0, 256),
                        r.Next(0, 256));

                    PointF p = new PointF(r.Next(Width), r.Next(Height));
                    RectangleF rect = new RectangleF(p, new SizeF(radius * 2, radius * 2));

                    if (!rects.Any(tmp => tmp.IntersectsWith(rect)))
                    {
                        rects.Add(rect);
                        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(c), rect);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        y--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: When i change the size of the points radius each point if i change it to 2.0f bmpWithPoints = GetBitmapWithEllipses(2.0f); or to 1.0f it will work fast. But if i change it to 4.0f it will take some time and if i change it to 6.0f or to 10.f it will take a very long time in minutes. Is there any way to make it wqork faster when changing the size ? If i make it size 1.0f and number of points 50 it's working fast. But when changing the radius on 50 points it will work a lot of time.

Comment: it is not in c# but may be helpful [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flQgnCUxHlw&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZiZxtDDRCi6uhfTH4FilpH&index=37). in the description is link to code ^^